# How to run Windows Telnet Client in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, telnet

I have installed telnet client in my Win 7. Now I try to run it in PowerShell. I need do this for running command `ewfmgr d: -commit` in remote hosts. I use

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName [MyComp] -scriptblock {cmd.exe /c "telnet"}
```

but nothing happens.  Is it possible to run telnet with CMD and transfer parameters (IP, username, password, command)?

I tried also

```
Invoke-Command -Command {cmd.exe /c C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe}

& "C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe}
```

I tried do the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841308/no-effects-in-running-telnet-get-telnet-in-powershell).

Comment: Nothing happens, as the Telnet client is interactive a program. It waits for user input. Scripting Telnet is a pain, can you use SSH instead?

Comment: If you must use telnet, at least use a telnet client that actually is scriptable, e.g. [`plink`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.69/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can open the telnet cliente from PowerShell with `Invoke-Item` like ex:

```
Invoke-Item "C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe"

start-sleep 5
```